# Runtime Approximation of a given algorithm

Tags: time, runtime, time-complexity

I tried to calculate the time-complexity of this algorithm:

```
for i = 1, ..., n
    for j = 1, ..., i
    {
        for k = 1, ..., j
            print k
        k = 2
        while (k < i)
            k = k^2
    }
```

I tried to calculate the time but I didn't succeed.

Comment: You might want to check this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 1):

**Please show a little more research effort next time.**

But still I will try it looking only at the complexity times.

```
for i = 1, ..., n     //n times
    for j = 1, ..., i  //n times
    {
        for k = 1, ..., j  //n times
            print k;  // constant
        k = 2;  //constant
        while (k < i) 
            k = k^2;  //log2n - 1
   }
```

Every loop is executed `n` times. The variable assignments are always constant, so *O(1)*. In the while loop k starts at 2 and after the first time k is 4. The second time through it becomes 16. Third time: 256... It is clearly logarithmic; So it will execute *O(log2(n))* times.

`n(n(n(O(1))+O(1) + log2n - 1)) = n(n(n + log2n) = n^2(n + log2n) = n^3 + n^2(log2n)` Since the base of the logarithm in time analysis is irrelevant, the 2 goes away. So `n^3 + n^2(log n)`. The defining term is `n^3` so that is in *O(n^3)*.

I hope that helps.